# Backup and restore CoreData

Tags: core-data, swift3, backup, ios10, restore

I would like to offer my users the possibility to email a backup of their data:

```
let filemanager = FileManager()
let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.libraryDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
let coreDataFilePath = documentsPath.appending("/Application Support/MyApp.sqlite")
let coreDataFile = filemanager.contents(atPath: coreDataFilePath)
print("\(coreDataFilePath)")

if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail()
{
    let mail = MFMailComposeViewController()
    mail.mailComposeDelegate = self
    mail.setSubject("Backup")
    mail.setMessageBody("Use this email to backup your data", isHTML: true)
    mail.addAttachmentData(coreDataFile!, mimeType: "myapp/sqlite", fileName: "myapp.madb")

    present(mail, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
else
{
    print("Mail services are not available. Please open the mail application and setup an email account.")
    return
}
```

But I'd like to restore the data and don't know how I should go about this. Especially that iOS 10 CoreData has changed.
And I'd like to do all of this without having to have to user restart the app.

I have this post as reference:
    [Best practices for core data store (sqlite) backup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3364240/best-practices-for-core-data-store-sqlite-backup?rq=1)

Comment: how large is the data set? email attachments are usually limited to 10-20 megabtyes, and at that size you could just as easily fetch all and format as JSON.

Comment: To be honest, I didn't think of that. Rookie mistake... :P I need to investigate. Anything to recommend?